# How can I effectively implement a Google Dataflow job with an API endpoint as the source?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Does anyone here have experience with using an API endpoint as the data source for a Google Dataflow job? We badly need help troubleshooting our issue.

In our project, we were previously tasked to develop a **Dataflow job (Flex template using Java)** that connects to the client's API endpoint (using OAuth2 authentication), then write the returned responses to a GCS bucket. We succeeded in development and unit testing, but suddenly we encountered problems while migrating to production.

## Situation

One of the API endpoint sources currently has ~192K records (both on dev and prod envs). Due to the nature of those endpoints, we could only retrieve 1000 records at a time from them, and as such, we have to manually handle the retrieval of each "page" of 1000 records.

## Current Implementation

To retrieve the records from the API endpoint, I wrote a method which retrieves the response records from the endpoint (loops to get each thousand due to the pagination) and stores them to a `List<String>` result object. After all records have been retrieved, the resulting `List<String>` object is returned and used as the input of the usual `Create.of(Collection<?>)` method as per Apache Beam API.

## Problem

Previously when we performed unit testing, we limited the maximum amount of records to retrieve from the API endpoints as we mainly focused on the core functionality required of the Dataflow job.

Now that we are migrating to production, we suddenly encountered a problem with this specific API endpoint source and its ~192K records. After almost 13 minutes of remaining in the job queue, the job suddenly fails with the timeout polling exception:

`Timeout in polling result file: gs://.../operation_result. Service account: <service-account> Image URL: <image-url>`

It is to be noted that for most of the time that the job remains in queue, it is still in the process of retrieving the records from the API endpoint. But it seems like the Dataflow job automatically terminates after ~10-15 mins if it takes too long on the queue before the pipeline is actually built. (Pattern: Always 12 min 40-50 sec before the job dies).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTDoa.png)

## Solution(s) attempted

We attempted to provide an explicit value of execution_timeout in the Cloud Composer DAG that triggers it, supplying this into default_args. However, this did not work out. Currently, we are out of other options on how to solve this. The last resort I thought of was to convert the List<String> generating method to an actual Apache Beam source. However, when I read on the documentation, I thought that it would be difficult to implement a `split()` method that allows the source to be split into parts so that workers could connect in parallel.

Comment: I've heard about interest of doing an "IO Connector for HTTP" in the Beam user list. Encourage interacting there. https://lists.apache.org/thread/xsp5r8cb86k03599vp1s2bzy0m673x44

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement a custom source. When you use a simple `beam.Create()` (I am only developing Beam in Python, but the concept is identical for Java) it will try to populate this `PCollection` before actually starting the pipeline. This is why you are encountering your timeout issue.

What you need to do, is to implement a custom source, using `Splittable DoFns`. This is not that easy to do, and also not that simple to describe, thus allow me to just reference the documentation [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns).